# Pandas dataframe.plot() - line graph - series values not plotted for first two index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

In the attached image (attached dataframe and plotted line graph snapshots) - series index ranges from 242.0 to 252.0 but data for index 242.0 and 243.0 is missing.
What is the issue here?

Following is the relevant code:

```py
import re
import json as js
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def plot(collector, run_type, stat_type):
       ax = plt.gca()
       run_info = collector.series[run_type]['info']
       dfs = []
       ctr_str = 'Type {}'
       ctr = 0
       for var in run_info:
           ctr += 1
           if not re.search(stat_type, var):
               continue
           var_info = run_info[var]
           try:
               dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({var: var_info['data']}, index=var_info['runs']))
           except:
               print(var_info['data'])
               print(var_info['runs'])
               x=1
       pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, sort=False).sort_index().plot(kind='line', ax=ax)
       plt.show(block=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 243, the values occur in those columns in which there is only one value in the entire column(Type1, Type2, and Type5), thus Line plot won't plot those lines. For 242, seems `nan` is breaking the line of the column. However you need to handle Nan before plotting.